# Using Suds for SOAP in python, are suds.client.Client objects thread safe?

Tags: python, soap, multithreading, suds

I'm using Suds to access a SOAP web service from python.  If I have multiple threading.Thread threads of execution, can each of them safely access the same suds.client.Client instance concurrently, or must I create separate Client objects for each thread?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know they are NOT thread safe.  You could safely use the same client object so long as you are using a queue or thread pool. That way when one thread is done with the client, the next one can use it.

For network-based events however, you should probably ask yourself which is better.  Threading or asynchronous network programming?  There was recently a [patch proposed to SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/312) to enable support for asynch sockets for use with event-based packages such as Twisted, greenlets, etc.

Comment: Note that even if you were using greenlets with suds, you wouldn't necessarily be able to share the same instance between green threads, either, since your thread can be scheduled out during I/O operations at which point the state of the client might be updated.