# Comparing async urlfetch to urllib2 with threads in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, urlfetch

I have to make [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds) runs asynchronously,
I was thinking about two ideas:

1. (easier) Run each suds call in separate thread because GAE python 2.7 runtime [allows](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27#Multithreading) it.
2. (much harder) Rewrite suds lib to run on top of async url fetch

I would like to use first option but don't know if it will be much slower than second one.

Maybe somebody more experienced in GAE could help me to choose ?

**UPDATE**

Result has to be in single web request, so I can't use task queues/mapreduce/backends

Comment: People still using SOAP??

Comment: I'd love a GAE version of suds, preferably using ndb async. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991864/using-suds-for-soap-in-python-are-suds-client-client-objects-thread-safe), suds is not a threadsafe library. So you'd have to create a new client for each thread that wants to utilize a suds client object. With that said, choice number 1 would be your best option.

Also, look [here](http://omiethenull.blogspot.com/2010/08/suds-and-appengine.html) for information on how to make the suds library work with caching on GAE.

**UPDATE**

Other techniques to try (for use-cases in which you don't need the result in a single web request):

**[Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) and [Pull Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull)**: (use this method if you plan to constantly be making calls)

Create always-on backends that store the suds client in memory and constantly poll a pull queue for tasks you need to perform. This way, you can push many tasks/calls your application needs to make and have multiple backends consuming the data in small chunks.

**[Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push)**:

(Use this method if you want to try and keep costs to a minimum and don't plan on consistently making many SOAP calls)

Create tasks and let AppEngine execute your needs across multiple instances. Just know there is no guarantee on when a task will execute, but in my experience this hasn't been an issue.

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, both ways are fine as far as I will keep separate Client instance per async call. 
But my question was if easier solution (1) will have performance downsides comparing to (2) solution ?

Comment: From my experience, the biggest CPU hit is loading my WSDL file in suds (with memcache enabled). The overhead of using threads vs NDB, IMHO, would be negligible. However, using NDB (method 2 described above) should technically be faster than creating a new thread for each client (method 1 described above) especially if you're already using NDB in your application. IIRC, there can only be 10 asynchronous URL fetch calls per request in production (I think it's per request, it might be per instance or application)

Comment: I've prepared some test (during it I am cloning SUDS client instance, so I am loading WSDL file only once):
1. make one SUDS call - takes 4s
2. make 10 synchronous SUDS calls - takes 40s
3. make 10 asynchronous SUDS calls - take more than 60s (DeadlineExceededError)

I think I've faced GIL problem, because SUDS call is not only I/O bound but CPU bound too (parsing XML message and creating SUDS structure).

Am I right ? What can I do ?

Comment: You are correct, there is a large CPU hit in suds (it is SOAP after all), but if you used method 1 above you should have been able to achieve some sort of speed increase with IO bound operations (such as the urlfetch calls). Can you post your code? I'll update my answer with additional ideas to try. Also make sure you run your tests in production, not on the dev_server as that will try and run things serially. Try using appstats to get a better idea of how your request is waiting on URLFetch calls vs CPU time vs other RPC calls. I know that suds created a ton of log spam, disabling that helps.

Comment: I've used this code https://gist.github.com/krotkiewicz/f741b05265ccc1927123 for tests I described above.

Comment: I would highly suggest using appstats to view the RPC calls your request is making and to figure out how much of the time looks to be IO bound vs CPU bound. If the IO is very small compared to the CPU, then that would explain everything. Again, there was a lot of logspam I had to disable (https://gist.github.com/someone1/38967c2f833aadb3c470)